# How to simply find substring in string?

Tags: lua

For example string.find not work correct:

```
print ( string.match("Test/(", "Test/(") )
```

second argument is submitted  as regexp, not simple string.

Answer (score 2):

```
print(string.match("Test/(", "Test/("))
```

Will cause the error message

> unfinished capture

`"Test/("` is not a valid Lua string pattern.

`(` is one of the magic characters `^$()%.[]*+-?` which have to be escaped by prepending `%` because they otherwise have a special meaning in defining patterns. `(` starts a *capture*. As it is not followed by `)` to end it your pattern contains an unfinished capture.

Use  `"Test/%("` instead to include the parenthesis into your search and avoid the error message.

Please refer to the [Lua Reference Manual - Patterns](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#6.4.1) for further details.

Answer (score -2):

Is this what you're looking for?

> `string.sub(s, i [, j])s:sub(i [,j])`
>
> Return a substring of the string passed. The substring starts at i. If the third argument j is not given, the substring will end at the end of the string. If the third argument is given, the substring
>   ends at and includes j

You can find documentation of the functions [here](http://lua-users.org/wiki/StringLibraryTutorial)

Comment: string.sub will give you a substring for specified character numbers, it will not find one.